# Four Fundamental Spaces without A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a question that has stumped me.  It asks "Without computing A, find bases for the four fundamental subspaces."  The $LU$ equation is as follows:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
6 & 1 & 0 \\
9 & 8 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$

I understand that 
$$N(A) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
2  \\
-1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and that there is no $N(A^T)$ because there are no zero rows in $U$, but I do not know what to do for the column/row spaces without computing $A$.  I could compute columns 1, 2, and 3 because it's not "$A$" but I know that's not what they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row space of $A=LU$ is the same as the rowspace of $U$ since $L$ is not singular. $L$ represents only a change of basis on the rows of $U$. The column space is the full span, since the null space is nothing.

Also, I think this is the null space:
$$N(A) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
1 \\
-2 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I copied my answer down incorrectly.  I completely forgot about how there were three pivots and the vectors were in R^3.  Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: What do you mean when you say column space is the full space SINCE THE NULL SPACE NOTHING?. I guess rank(A) =3, nullity(A)=1. And the basis for col(A) are just $Lu_1, Lu_2, Lu_3$ where $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are the first three columns of $U$

Comment: @Upstart I think I may not have worded that well, and it was a long time ago now! I must have been referring to N(A^T) being nothing as stated in the question, sorry if that is not too helpful

Answer (score 0):

If we are given two matrices $A$ and $B$, then the columns of $AB$ are linear combinations of the columns of $A$ and the rows of $AB$ are the linear combinations of the rows of $B$. This follows immediately from block multiplication
$$AB = \begin{pmatrix} A\mathbf{b_1} & \cdots & A\mathbf{b_n}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{a_1}^\mathrm{T}B \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{a_m}^\mathrm{T}B\end{pmatrix}$$
where $a_i$ and $b_i$ denote the row/column vectors of $A$ and $B$ respectively. From this, what can you conclude?